# Scala: using Future/ParSeq for parallel Spark querying?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parallel-processing

I have several different queries I need to perform on several different parquet files using Spark. Each of the queries is different, and has its own function which applies it. For example:

```
def query1(sqtx: sqlContext): DataFrame = {
  sqtx.sql("select clients as people, reputation from table1") }


def query2(sqtx: sqlContext): DataFrame = {
  sqtx.sql("select passengers as people, reputation from table2") }
```

and so on. As you can see, while all the queries are different, the schema of all the outputs is identical.

After querying, I want to use `unionAll` on all the successful outputs. And here comes my question - how? Using `ParSeq.map` is not possible here, since the mapping will be different for every query, and using `Future` doesn't really seems to fit in this case (I need to use `onComplete` on each one, see if it failed or not, etc.)

Any ideas how to do this simply?

Comment: If you union everything just write it as it is and let scheduler do its work.

Comment: @zero323 you mean to not use any parallelism and let Spark do it when it unions?

Comment: Yup. Queries you show don't perform any data processing. The only thing you could parallelize here is SQL parsing and building execution plan.

Comment: @zero323 thanks :)